# Cursor adapter and sqlite example

Tags: android, database, sqlite, android-layout, android-cursoradapter

Hello 
I am looking for sample code in which cursor adapter is used with sqlite?

Comment: This is not off topic at all.  Asking how to code a specific item is the lifeblood of StackOverflow.

Comment: Here is the simple answer: https://queception.com/question.php?question=106

Answer (score 105, accepted):

### Really simple example.

Here is a really simple, but very effective, example. Once you have the basics down you can easily build off of it.

There are two main parts to using a **Cursor Adapter** with SQLite:

1. Create a proper **Cursor** from the Database.
2. Create a custom **Cursor Adapter** that takes the **Cursor** data from the database and pairs it with the **View** you intend to represent the data with.

#### 1. Create a proper Cursor from the Database.

In your Activity:

```java
SQLiteOpenHelper sqLiteOpenHelper = new SQLiteOpenHelper( 
        context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);

SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase = sqLiteOpenHelper.getReadableDatabase();

String query = "SELECT * FROM clients ORDER BY company_name ASC"; // No trailing ';'

Cursor cursor = sqLiteDatabase.rawQuery(query, null); 

ClientCursorAdapter adapter = new ClientCursorAdapter(
        this, R.layout.clients_listview_row, cursor, 0 );

this.setListAdapter(adapter);
```

#### 2. Create a Custom Cursor Adapter.

*Note: Extending from `ResourceCursorAdapter` assumes you use XML to create your views.*

```java
public class ClientCursorAdapter extends ResourceCursorAdapter {

    public ClientCursorAdapter(Context context, int layout, Cursor cursor, int flags) {
        super(context, layout, cursor, flags);
    }

    @Override
    public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {
        TextView name = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.name);
        name.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("name")));

        TextView phone = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.phone);
        phone.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("phone")));
    }
}
```

Comment: I think this deserves more points.  It's very clear and helpful for understanding.

Comment: Thanks @Chris. If it helps just you, it'd be worth the effort. :)

Comment: "duplicate" or not, this answer is the top google search for "cursoradapter example" and is the clearest I've seen.

Comment: Here is the simple answer: https://queception.com/question.php?question=106

Answer (score 38):

**In Android, How to use a Cursor with a raw query in sqlite:**

```
Cursor c = sampleDB.rawQuery("SELECT FirstName, Age FROM mytable " +
           "where Age > 10 LIMIT 5", null);

if (c != null ) {
    if  (c.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            String firstName = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("FirstName"));
            int age = c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex("Age"));
            results.add("" + firstName + ",Age: " + age);
        }while (c.moveToNext());
    }
}
c.close();
```

Comment: Great example. Let me suggest a few improvements to shorten it: 1. Remove `if (c != null)`. Reason: [`rawQuery` won't return null](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#rawQuery), and if it does, there is some bug in the Sqlite implementation and the program should crash and send a bug report instead of silently doing nothing. ...

Comment: ... 2. Remove `if (c.moveToFirst())` and replace do-while with a `while (c.moveToNext()) { ... }` loop. Reason: [`rawQuery` always returns a Cursor positioned before the first row](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#rawQuery), so the first `moveToNext` will do exactly what moveToFirst would do. ...

Comment: ... 3. Put `try {` after the call to `rawQuery`, and put `} finally { ... }` around `c.close()`. That way, the cursor will be closed correctly in case of an exception during the cursor execution.

Answer (score 20):

CursorAdapter Example with Sqlite

```
...
DatabaseHelper helper = new DatabaseHelper(this);
aListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.aListView);
Cursor c = helper.getAllContacts();
CustomAdapter adapter = new CustomAdapter(this, c);
aListView.setAdapter(adapter);
...

class CustomAdapter extends CursorAdapter {
    // CursorAdapter will handle all the moveToFirst(), getCount() logic for you :)

    public CustomAdapter(Context context, Cursor c) {
        super(context, c);
    }

    public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {
        String id = cursor.getString(0);
        String name = cursor.getString(1);
        // Get all the values
        // Use it however you need to
        TextView textView = (TextView) view;
        textView.setText(name);
    }

    public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {
        // Inflate your view here.
        TextView view = new TextView(context);
        return view;
    }
}

private final class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "db_name";
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
    private static final String CREATE_TABLE_TIMELINE = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS table_name (_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, name varchar);";

    public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE_TIMELINE);
        db.execSQL("INSERT INTO ddd (name) VALUES ('One')");
        db.execSQL("INSERT INTO ddd (name) VALUES ('Two')");
        db.execSQL("INSERT INTO ddd (name) VALUES ('Three')");
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    }

    public Cursor getAllContacts() {
        String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM table_name;
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
        return cursor;
    }
}
```