# Why am I getting NullPointerException here?

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception

I have this code in one of my activity's onCreate Method

```
    GetNews newsReporter = new GetNews(getApplicationContext());
    try{
        News[] allNews = newsReporter.getAllNews();
        Log.d("News Count", String.valueOf(allNews.length));
        String[] timestamps = new String[allNews.length];
        String[] texts = new String[allNews.length];

        for(int i=0;i<allNews.length;i++)
        {
//          timestamps[i] = allNews[i].getNewsTime();
            texts[i] = allNews[i].getNewsText();
//          Log.d("TimeStamp", timestamps[i]);
            Log.d("Text", texts[i]);
        }
    }catch(Exception e){
        Log.e("Error News", e.toString());
    }
```

News Count Displays 6 in Logcat, which means News[] is not null.

But I receive NullPointerException on Line texts[i] = allNews[i].getNewsTime();

this is my News Class

```
    public class News {

    private int id;
    private String timestamp;
    private String text;


    public News(int i,String t, String ti)
    {   
        this.id=i;
        this.text = t;
        this.timestamp = ti;
    }

    public String getNewsTime()
    {
        return this.timestamp;
    }

    public String getNewsText()
    {
        return this.text;
    }
}
```

P.S. News is stored in a SQLitedatabase, when i pulled the database from my DDMS, it contains all 6 rows with valid values none of them is null.

Edit:
This is my GetAllNews Method

```
public News[] getAllNews(){


        SQLiteDatabase db = ConMan.OpenDBConnection();
        try{
            Cursor cursor = db.query(News_Table, Columns, null, null, null, null, null);
            if(cursor!=null)
            {
                cursor.moveToFirst();
            }

            News[] allNews = new News[cursor.getCount()];
            int i =0;
            while(cursor.isLast()){

                allNews[i] =  new News(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)),
                    cursor.getString(1),cursor.getString(2));
                cursor.moveToNext();
                i++;

            }

            db.close();
            ConMan.close();

            return allNews;


        }catch(Exception e)
        {
            Log.e("News DB Errors", e.getMessage());
        }

        return null;

    }
```

Comment: Looks like your text is null

Comment: Looks like `allNews[i]` is null. Put a logging statement or debugging breakpoint there and I'll bet this is the case.

Comment: News[] allNews = newsReporter.getAllNews(); at least one entry in the array is null, not the text

Comment: I don't think this could be the case

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is in the newsReporter.getAllNews() method.  Looks like it is returning the array without the value initialized.

```
News[] allNews = newsReporter.getAllNews();
```

Meaning,

**allNews.length** might get you some value.  But at each index, you are missing the value or at least one or more of the indexes are missing the value in the array.

Do the printing like below to see if you have values

```
for (News news : allNews)
    System.out.println(news);
```

Looks like it is not going into the following block at all.

```
while(cursor.isLast()){
   allNews[i] =  new News(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)),
                cursor.getString(1),cursor.getString(2));
   cursor.moveToNext();
   i++;
}
```

Check whether **cursor.isLast()** method is returning true to get into this loop.

Comment: Yes it is printing out null !

Comment: Cool, check your getAllNews() method for the issue.  Good luck!

Comment: i have added the method could you please help ?

Comment: @IshanKhanna I have made an edit to the answer, you can check that.

Comment: well if i have a count of 6 displayed with this         Log.d("News Count", String.valueOf(allNews.length));
why do you feel that it is not entering into the while loop ?

Comment: you can just check by debugging; put a breakpoint inside the loop

Comment: Your initialization happens at News[] allNews = new News[cursor.getCount()];  But it never assigns the value then.

Comment: Because it will return `false` to the first 5 elements :D. Actually, try `while(cursor.moveToNext())` it will return `false` after you are past the last element (and remember to remove the other call to `moveToNext` from inside the loop).

Comment: This post may also be helpfull: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5457699/cursor-adapter-and-sqlite-example

Answer (score 1):

```
        texts[i] = allNews[i].getNewsText();
```

Most possibly, allNews[someIndex] is null. when called getnewsText() on null throws NPE.
best test is to output allNews[i] or check if it isnull.

```
     System.out.println(allNews[i]==null)
```

Answer (score 0):

An array of `size` **6** can have **6** `null` references. Print each of your `News` objects in `allNews`, I bet 10 Obamas that at least one position in the array is `null`.

Answer (score 0):

You are saying that allNews[] is not null, so it must be that News[] contains a null, so that allNews[i].getNewsText() throws the exception.