# android - DequeueBuffer - dequeue native buffer fail

Tags: android, debugging

I have an application where I use list view (I read content from database) everything works fine until I scroll few "pages" then it drops this error:

```
11-03 08:44:36.273: W/Adreno-EGLSUB(29015): <DequeueBuffer:606>: dequeue native buffer fail: Unknown error 2147483646, buffer=0x0, handle=0x0
11-03 08:44:36.273: W/Adreno-EGL(29015): <qeglDrvAPI_eglSwapBuffers:3692>: EGL_BAD_SURFACE
11-03 08:44:36.273: W/HardwareRenderer(29015): EGL error: EGL_BAD_SURFACE
11-03 08:44:36.273: W/HardwareRenderer(29015): Mountain View, we've had a problem here. Switching back to software rendering.
11-03 08:44:36.493: E/Surface(29015): dequeueBuffer: IGraphicBufferProducer::requestBuffer failed: -2147483646
11-03 08:44:36.493: E/Surface(29015): dequeueBuffer failed (Unknown error 2147483646)
11-03 08:44:36.493: E/ViewRootImpl(29015): Could not lock surface
11-03 08:44:36.493: E/ViewRootImpl(29015): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
11-03 08:44:36.493: E/ViewRootImpl(29015):  at android.view.Surface.nativeLockCanvas(Native Method)
11-03 08:44:36.493: E/ViewRootImpl(29015):  at android.view.Surface.lockCanvas(Surface.java:253)
11-03 08:44:36.493: E/ViewRootImpl(29015):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.drawSoftware(ViewRootImpl.java:2808)
11-03 08:44:36.493: E/ViewRootImpl(29015):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.draw(ViewRootImpl.java:2782)
11-03 08:44:36.493: E/ViewRootImpl(29015):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performDraw(ViewRootImpl.java:2620)
11-03 08:44:36.493: E/ViewRootImpl(29015):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:2188)
11-03 08:44:36.493: E/ViewRootImpl(29015):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1249)
11-03 08:44:36.493: E/ViewRootImpl(29015):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6585)
11-03 08:44:36.493: E/ViewRootImpl(29015):  at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:803)
11-03 08:44:36.493: E/ViewRootImpl(29015):  at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:603)
11-03 08:44:36.493: E/ViewRootImpl(29015):  at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:573)
11-03 08:44:36.493: E/ViewRootImpl(29015):  at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:789)
11-03 08:44:36.493: E/ViewRootImpl(29015):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
11-03 08:44:36.493: E/ViewRootImpl(29015):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
11-03 08:44:36.493: E/ViewRootImpl(29015):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
11-03 08:44:36.493: E/ViewRootImpl(29015):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5586)
11-03 08:44:36.493: E/ViewRootImpl(29015):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-03 08:44:36.493: E/ViewRootImpl(29015):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
11-03 08:44:36.493: E/ViewRootImpl(29015):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1268)
11-03 08:44:36.493: E/ViewRootImpl(29015):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1084)
11-03 08:44:36.493: E/ViewRootImpl(29015):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
11-03 08:44:36.503: E/Surface(29015): dequeueBuffer failed (Invalid argument)
11-03 08:44:36.503: E/ViewRootImpl(29015): Could not lock surface
11-03 08:44:36.503: E/ViewRootImpl(29015): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
11-03 08:44:36.503: E/ViewRootImpl(29015):  at android.view.Surface.nativeLockCanvas(Native Method)
11-03 08:44:36.503: E/ViewRootImpl(29015):  at android.view.Surface.lockCanvas(Surface.java:253)
11-03 08:44:36.503: E/ViewRootImpl(29015):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.drawSoftware(ViewRootImpl.java:2808)
11-03 08:44:36.503: E/ViewRootImpl(29015):  at  android.view.ViewRootImpl.draw(ViewRootImpl.java:2782)
11-03 08:44:36.503: E/ViewRootImpl(29015):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performDraw(ViewRootImpl.java:2620)
11-03 08:44:36.503: E/ViewRootImpl(29015):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:2188)
11-03 08:44:36.503: E/ViewRootImpl(29015):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1249)
11-03 08:44:36.503: E/ViewRootImpl(29015):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6585)
11-03 08:44:36.503: E/ViewRootImpl(29015):  at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:803)
11-03 08:44:36.503: E/ViewRootImpl(29015):  at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:603)
11-03 08:44:36.503: E/ViewRootImpl(29015):  at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:573)
11-03 08:44:36.503: E/ViewRootImpl(29015):  at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:789)
11-03 08:44:36.503: E/ViewRootImpl(29015):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
11-03 08:44:36.503: E/ViewRootImpl(29015):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
11-03 08:44:36.503: E/ViewRootImpl(29015):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
11-03 08:44:36.503: E/ViewRootImpl(29015):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5586)
11-03 08:44:36.503: E/ViewRootImpl(29015):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-03 08:44:36.503: E/ViewRootImpl(29015):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
11-03 08:44:36.503: E/ViewRootImpl(29015):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1268)
11-03 08:44:36.503: E/ViewRootImpl(29015):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1084)
11-03 08:44:36.503: E/ViewRootImpl(29015):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

(I am testing application on Samsung Galaxy S5.)
I am a beginner android developer and I have never seen error like this. Could anyone tell me which way should I continue the search ? I am lost :( thanks

listView :

```
listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);
listView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

adapter :

```
@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return Model.getInstance().getDatabase().getRow(position);
}
```

Comment: You should post some code. How do you read the database? How do you create the listview?

Comment: Please let me know what do u need more. This class is extended from Fragment and I only want to copy what is important. Thanks for your time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never do any database calls inside the getItem method. Pre-load all the data or use a CursorAdapter.

I would suggest you use a CursorAdapter for this kind of code: [Cursor adapter and sqlite example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5457699/cursor-adapter-and-sqlite-example)