# Android listview baseadapter and setOnItemClickListener cannot function in same time

Tags: android, listview, baseadapter, onitemclicklistener

i manage to do when i click the item in my listview , beside the column will show a tick over there, but now i have a problem in when i click on my item the tick will show but there is no function for my onitemclicklistener event. how to let this two function work in same time. sorry for my english, hope can understand

**this is my setOnItemClickListener event**

```
 condimentlist.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
      @Override
  public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
     TextView condimentitem =(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.condcb);
     String citem= condimentitem.getText().toString();

     ArrayList<String> data = new ArrayList<String>();
     data.add(citem);

     String array[] = data.toArray(new String[0]);
    for (int j = 0; j < array.length; j++) {
    remark.append(String.valueOf(array[j]));
                      }
 ------condimentitem.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()-------
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                int visibility = btntick.getVisibility();
                if(visibility == View.VISIBLE)
                {
                    btntick.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }
                else
                {
                    btntick.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }
            }
        });

               }
 });
```

**this is my baseadapter to contor the tick**

```
 public class condimentlist extends BaseAdapter {

    LayoutInflater mInflater;

    private ArrayList<Integer> positions = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    public ArrayList<Integer> getPositions() {
        return positions;
    }

    public condimentlist() {
        mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(getActivity());
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return CondimentList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.condimentlistview_details, null);
        }
        condcb = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.condcb);
        final TextView tremark = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.Tremark);
        btntick = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.iv_tick);

    Condiment myObj = CondimentList.get(position);
    condcb.setText("" + myObj.getCondimentName());


 -----------convertView.performClick ();------------------
        return convertView;
    }
```

**condimentlistview_details.xml**

```
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/condcb"
        android:text="Press"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:textSize="18sp" />

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="15dp"
        android:layout_height="15dp"
        android:background="@drawable/tick"
        android:id="@+id/iv_tick"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="150dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="150dp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: can you please share your `condimentlistview_details`  layout file.

Comment: It because of your `TextView` like condcb is a conflict with `condimentlist.setOnItemClickListener`

Comment: Maybe, you can set the setOnClickListener over the tick: int the  `btntick` !!
`btntick.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()`

Comment: what action you want to do, to toggle visible / gone of the tick when you click your menu item?

Comment: @kggoh nope, when i cllick on the listview item the tick will beside the column

Comment: i post below, see if that example helps you.

Answer (score 1):

I think problem is **ImageButton** in your listview Row xml file.

Put `android:focusable="false"` , and see it works!!!

```
<ImageButton
    android:layout_width="15dp"
    android:layout_height="15dp"
    android:background="@drawable/tick"
    android:id="@+id/iv_tick"
    android:visibility="gone"
    android:focusable="false"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="150dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="150dp" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Add   `convertView.performClick()` inside `condcb.OnClick` method in adapter.

Comment: thanks, it dosen't work , i still get the same result

Comment: Put your logic at one place whichever get called.

Comment: i combine my logic into my onitemclicklistener, but both function cannot be work, i edited my question code, is it my way is correct?

Answer (score 0):

Below is one of the question i answered before, you may need to create a list with one of the element of boolean as a flag. When you select, you turn that flag into true. Hope it helps.

[enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39696340/accessing-listview-checkbox-in-android/39697518#39697518)

Answer (score 0):

Write this code inside **BASE ADAPTER's** `getView()`

```
condimentitem.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()-------
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                int visibility = btntick.getVisibility();
                if(visibility == View.VISIBLE)
                {
                    btntick.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }
                else
                {
                    btntick.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

You could define a `static ArrayList` in your activity class, then retrieve everything from that array list in the base adapter with a Hashmap. Then, you could use `SetOnItemClickListener` in your activity class to get the correct value of each row by referencing the activity's array list's position.

Works for me flawlessly. Let me know if you need example code.